# Cordova build is unable to resolve target even though target is installed

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to setup a phonegap project and keep getting the following error when I run `cordova build android`:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Applications/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/david/Projects/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:542: Unable to resolve project target 'android-L'
```

The weird thing about it is that I have the android-L-Target installed. When i run `android list targets` I get:

```
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-3"
...
id: 11 or "android-L"
 Name: Android L (Preview)
 Type: Platform
 API level: L
 Revision: 4
 Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
Tag/ABIs : android-tv/armeabi-v7a, android-tv/x86, default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86, default/x86_64
```

Moreover I have set the project-target explicitly to another android-version. Like this: `android update project -p . -t android-17` I also tried doing this adding the --subprojects parameter. Still I get the BUILD FAILED error above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found it out myself: I opened the Project in Eclipse right clicked the Project-name and chose "properties". In the properties-menu on the left-side, I chose "Android". In the libraries panel was a library with a red cross in front of it. I suppose that this library was set to target=android-L. I removed it and could subsequently build the project.